# Unable to replace NaN value with a date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, nan

Trying to replace a `NaN` in a `datetime` column with another `datetime` object from the same pandas dataframe.  I have tried set_value, at, `loc`. They all result in `nan` being saved instead of the actual date.
Here is the most recent code I tried, seeing that the `updated_date` was being saved as Timestamp, I tried converting it to `datetime`. But even here it saves it as `nan`.
any idea?

```
updated_date = df[column_to_fix_with].iloc[index].to_pydatetime()
df.set_value(col_w_dates_to_fix, index, updated_date)
```

Comment: Hi There, welcome to SO please see [ask] and [mcve] please post a sample of your data with an expected output.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to fill empty column `column_to_fill` with values from the same dataframe `df` with values from column `column_from` use:

```
df['column_to_fill'] = df['column_to_fill'].fillna(df['column_from'])
```